# Proving Shift Rule and the limit

Tags: calculus

Let k be a fixed natural number. Show that the limit to the infinity of the sequence an = the limit to the infinity of the sequence an+k.

Comment: what are your thoughts on the matter?

Comment: Mathematical expressions can be posted here using [MathJax](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and $\LaTeX$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lim \limits_{n\to\infty} a_n = L$

Recalling the definition of limit,

$\forall \epsilon > 0\, \exists N >0$ such that $n>N\implies |a_n - L|<\epsilon$

How would you make that work for $a_{n+k}$?

Comment: yea i got to this place too, but I have no idea how to continue. I've tried adding k to n so that n+k>N but it doesn't sound right to me

Comment: If k>0 then n+k > N and you are done.  If k could be negative.  Then you can can make M > N-k and when n>M ==> |a_n+k - L| < e.